# How to validate a DbType.Guid as a Valid Parameter before calling a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am building a recursive function in C# to call a set of stored procedures (I do not want to build one calling function for each stored procedure).

One of the parameters is a `uniqueidentifier`. However, if I send a parameter using the wrong type (a string for example), I get an exception:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier

How can I check if the parameter to be sent to the stored procedure is a `DbType.Guid` ?

This is my calling function, and if the checking task could be done PRIOR to calling the stored procedure, this would be the best solution:

```
public SqlDataReader GetDataFromDB(string Cmdtext, CommandType CmdType)
{
    _conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    // Create Connection
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_conString);

    // Create Command
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = Cmdtext;
    cmd.CommandType = CmdType;

    //// Create ADO.NET parameters
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", _User);

    if (Cmdtext == "SpecificStoredProcedure")
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mGUID", _mGUID);
    }

    //// Return DataReader
    con.Open();

    return cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}
```

Comment: can you not check prior if the GUID and or String Contains `-` and if you really want to make sure check to see if it has at least 4 `-` ? and pass in the `_mGUID`  as a parameter and check that as well I would restructure where you are doing the GUID Check or make that part of the conditional check along with stored procedure name else just use stored procedure name with said parameters..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `Guid.TryParse` , `Guid.Parse`
- create a helper method where you create a new Guid with the string,
  return true if success , catch the exception and return false if
  exception

  ```
  try
  { 
      Guid guid = new Guid(data) 
      return true; 
  }
  catch(Exception)
  { 
     return false; 
  }
  ```